# How can i fetch a specific to a variable

Tags: python, django

Hello i want to fetch a specific field to a variable

For that I have Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Here I want to fetch total field in a variable.But I am new for that reason I am really confused about this topic

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy. Since you have defined your models already. All you have to do is to use it in your view.py and then in your templates. Exaple is the below:

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def Index(request):
   Orders = Order.objects.all()
   context = {"Orders":Orders}
   return render(request, "template/page.html", context)
```

page.html

```
{% for order in Orders %}
   {{order.total}}
   {{order.price}}
   # You can do the same to other field to get them
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another method you can use. You would have to define a method or property for the field and then call it in your templates.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.total
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def Index(request):
   Orders = Order.objects.all()
   context = {"Orders":Orders}
   return render(request, "template/page.html", context)
```

page.html

```
{% for order in Orders %}
   {{order.get_total}}
   # You can do the same to other field to get them
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not like this i want assign the total field in a variable then i want to subtract with another field @coderboy

Comment: What field do you what to subtract, so I could edit the codes